# How to use xargs to set and change variables on the fly?

Tags: bash, command-line, docker, yaml

I'm trying to perform `docker save -o` on all images in a docker-compose.yaml file in one command.

what I've managed to do is:

`cat docker-compose.yaml | grep image` and this will give:

```
 image: hub.myproject.com/dev/frontend:prod_v_1_2
 image: hub.myproject.com/dev/backend:prod_v_1_2
 image: hub.myproject.com/dev/abd:v_2_3
 image: hub.myproject.com/dev/xyz:v_4_6
```

I need to perform the following command for each image:

`docker save -o frontend_prod_v_1_2.tar hub.myproject.com/dev/frontend:prod_v_1_2`

What I have managed to achieve is :

`cat docker-compose.yml | grep image | cut -d ':' -f 2,3` which gives:

```
 hub.myproject.com/dev/frontend:prod_v_1_2
 hub.myproject.com/dev/backend:prod_v_1_2
 hub.myproject.com/dev/abd:v_2_3
 hub.myproject.com/dev/xyz:v_4_6
```

I can furthur do:

`cat docker-compose.yml | grep image | cut -d ':' -f 2,3 | cut -d '/' -f3 | cut -d ':' -f1,2`

which gives:

```
 frontend:prod_v_1_2
 backend:prod_v_1_2
 abd:v_2_3
 xyz:v_4_6
```

Then I'm not sure what to do. I have tried to use `xargs` to pass as a variable but I don't know how to change xargs from `frontend:prod_v_1_2` to `frontend_prod_v_1_2.tar` on the fly in the command line. Also, I still need the full image name and tag at the end.

I'm looking for something like:

``` cat docker-compose.yml | grep image | cut -d ':' -f 2,3 | xargs -I {} docker save -o ``{} | cut -d '/' -f3 | cut -d ':' -f1,2 | xargs -I {} {}.tar``  {} ```

any bash magicians can offer a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pipeline approach could convoluted as you add more and more commands. Just use the prowess of your native shell, in this case `bash` for operations like this. Pipe the output of `grep image docker-compose.yml` into a `while..read` loop and perform substitutions with it.

In a proper shell script this could be done as

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# '<(..)' is a bash construct i.e process substitution to run the command and make 
# its output appear as if it were from a file
# https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution

while IFS=: read -r _ image; do
    # Strip off the part up the last '/'
    iname="${image##*/}"
    # Remove ':' from the image name and append '.tar' to the string and 
    # replace spaces in the image name
    docker save -o "${iname//:/_}.tar" "${image// }"
done < <(grep image docker-compose.yml)
```

On the command line, instead of `xargs` I would use `awk` directly to run the docker save operation

```
awk '/image/ { 
       n = split($NF, arr, "/"); 
       iname = arr[n]".tar"; 
       sub(":", "_", iname); fname = $2;  
       cmd = "docker save -o " iname " " fname; 
       system(cmd);
    }' docker-compose.yml
```

Comment: awk is so powerful!

Comment: a follow up question:  what is the meaning of  `_`  in `read -r _ image`?  I've searched a lot but couldn't find any information about using underscore with `read` ..